# Spring CXF Soap Web Service Under Tomcat: No Services Found

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm trying to set-up a simple CXF Web Service running on Tomcat with CXF and Spring:

I have a Web Application initializer to bootstrap the CXF servlet:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
  @Override
  protected void registerContextLoaderListener(ServletContext servletContext)
  {
    CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("cxf", cxfServlet);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
  }

  .....
}
```

I have a Spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration
{
  @Bean
  public Endpoint endPoint()
  {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxf(), eorthoWebService());
    endpoint.getHandlers().add(inboundRequestHandler());
    endpoint.getHandlers().add(outboundRequestHandler());
    //the below works and uses cxf's embedded Jetty server
    //endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9090/services/EorthoWebService");
    //this doesn't work
    endpoint.publish("/EorthoWebService");

    return endpoint;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringBus cxf()
  {
    return new SpringBus();
  }

  @Bean
  public EorthoWebService eorthoWebService()
  {
    return new EorthoWebServiceImpl();
  }
}
```

I have a Web Service implementation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.aoa.eortho.ws.service.EorthoWebService")
@SchemaValidation(type = SchemaValidationType.IN)
public class EorthoWebServiceImpl implements EorthoWebService {

    @WebMethod
    public RulesEngineOrthodonticSubmissionResponseEnv processRequest(RulesEngineOrthodonticSubmissionRequestEnv requestEnvelope) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I hit /services I get the output:

> No services have been found.

The only way I can it to work is by publishing as below which seems to publish it to an embedded Jetty server rather than the Tomcat instance it is deployed to:

```
endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9090/services/EorthoWebService");
```

What am I missing to get it working on Tomcat using:

```
endpoint.publish("/EorthoWebService");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you're missing is the spring contextscanning.

From [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/) -- [A Guide to Apache CXF with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-cxf-with-spring)

> > First, a Spring application context is created and configured to register a class containing configuration metadata:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context 
    = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(ServiceConfiguration.class);
```

> > The ServiceConfiguration class is annotated with the @Configuration annotation to provide bean definitions. This class is discussed in the next subsection.
> >     The following snippet shows how the Spring application context is added to the servlet context:

```
container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
```

So, the complete class is:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(ServiceConfiguration.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new CXFServlet());
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        dispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
    }
}
```

Which is different from your `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` extended class but when i override `onStartup` instead of `registerContextLoaderListener` it seems to work just as well. Hopefully this is enough to get you sorted out.

Also, my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxf(), new HelloWorldImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/HelloWorld");
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Karl. I have also found that simply not creating the SpringBus bean and calling `EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(new HelloWorldImpl());` also fixed the problem.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Didn't try that. Thanks.

Comment: For me personally, leaving out the SpringBus parameter when constructing the EndpointImpl was the cause of the error.

The service was registered on one SpringBus, while another SpringBus (the bean one) actually handled the HTTP requests and didn't find any registered services.